# Is there a faster way than for loops to use facet_wrap_paginate in R?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, vectorization, facet-wrap

I'm trying to use `facet_wrap_paginate()` from the `ggforce` package to apply `facet_wrap()` to a large number of facets that would be unreadable if on a single page. However, using a `for()` loop (as described in the vignette) to create each page is incredibly slow for my dataset, so I was wondering how I would go about vectorizing this process? Part of the issue I suspect is that I have nested the `for()` loop into a function so that I can apply it to a number of scenarios, and I'm guessing that it is effectively rebuilding the entire plot every time before selecting the correct page to display. If my assumption is correct, is there a way to instead of rebuilding the plot each time, just select the page from the plot that has been stored in memory?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

df <- mtcars

hist_plts <- function(data, var, title_vars, pages, x_low_lim = 0, x_up_lim = 50) {
    for (i in 1:pages) {
        plot <- data %>%
            filter({{ var }} >= x_low_lim, {{ var }} < x_up_lim) %>%
            ggplot(
                aes(
                    x = {{ var }} 
                )
            ) +
            geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
            labs(
                title = paste0("Count of mpg by ", title_vars),
                x = "MPG",
                y = " Count",
                caption = paste0("Page ", i, " of ", pages)
            ) +
            scale_x_continuous() +
            facet_wrap_paginate(
                ~cyl,
                scales = "free",
                nrow = 1,
                ncol = 1,
                page = i)
        
        print(plot)
    }
}

hist_plts(
    data = df,
    var = mpg,
    title_vars = "Cylinders",
    pages = 3)
```

Comment: After reading a bit [how ggplot2 works internally](https://ggplot2-book.org/internals.html) and looking at the [source code](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/blob/master/R/facet_wrap_paginate.R) (especially lines 70/71), it seems that at least all steps in the data processing and most steps in the `gtable` formation are performed in every loop and then the corresponding facets for the given page are selected. However, the actual plotting is only done after these steps. I'm not sure if you could change `facet_wrap_paginate`/`FacetWrapPaginate` in a trivial way

Comment: Thanks for your comment and directing me towards those pages. It doesn't seem like there is a simple way to alter `facet_wrap_paginate()`. Do you happen to know of another way (other than `facet_wrap_paginate()`) that might reduce some of the computation burden? Thanks,

Comment: If you don't need any layers that depend on the complete dataset, you could try to split your data prior to plotting and only generate some facets (basically manually doing the `facet_wrap_paginate`). But I'm not sure if this is faster, you can try it out